# Create an input link in the button

Tags: html

How can I input a link in the button when I press the button?

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <span class="sold-out-tag position-top-right">Best Seller</span>
  <button class="btn custom-btn position-bottom-right"> Add to cart</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If all you want is to follow the link when the button is clicked, you can make it a link and style it so it looks like a button.

Comment: Just add button code in between link such as <a href="somelin"><button>Test</button></a>

Comment: @Hkachhia No. that is a VERY bad idea. Poor UX and hard to give accessibility

Comment: Why do you want a link? Instead use some JavaScript to add the ID of the item to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can trigger a link by JavaScript.

```
<button 
    onclick="window.location(this.getAttribute('data-link'))"
    data-link="/hello">go to hello</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use an anchor tag instead of the button and make it look like a button.

HTML:

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <a class="btn custom-btn position-bottom-right"> Add to cart</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.custom-btn {
  border: medium dashed green;
}
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
<button class="btn custom-btn position-bottom-right" onclick="location.href='yourlink.com';"> Add to Cart </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the anchor tag and provide a [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) class for the button, like,

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="link"> Add to Cart</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<a href='http://my-link.com'>
    <button class="GFG">
        Click Here
    </button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the label "Add to cart" matches the expectations, we'd be talking about a form. A form that causes an element to be added typically uses the [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) method:

```
<form class="buttons" method="post" action="/path/to/add/to/cart/script">
  <input type="hidden" name="product" value="123">
  <span class="sold-out-tag position-top-right">Best Seller</span>
  <button class="btn custom-btn position-bottom-right"> Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

Alternatively, there's [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) as well:

```
<form class="buttons" method="get" action="/path/to/add/to/cart/script?product=123">
  <span class="sold-out-tag position-top-right">Best Seller</span>
  <button class="btn custom-btn position-bottom-right"> Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

Since GET doesn't carry additional payload, you'll get the same effect with a regular anchor:

```
<a href="/path/to/add/to/cart/script?product=123">Add to cart</a>
```

You don't want search engine spiders to populate carts, so you typically leave GET for data fetching.